# python selenium mouse scroll wheel click

Tags: python, selenium

I have a question about is it possible to simulate a mouse scroll wheel click in python selenium ( when you click on a link a new tab opens in the browser ) or something similar. The website I am using is javascript based so I can`t really see physical links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to execute javascript code. Mouse scroll wheel click has `1` as number representation according to [MouseEvent.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) documentation:

> 0: Main button pressed, usually the left button or the un-initialized
>   state
>
> **1: Auxiliary button pressed, usually the wheel button or the middle
>   button (if present)**
>
> 2: Secondary button pressed, usually the right button
>
> 3: Fourth button, typically the Browser Back button
>
> 4: Fifth button, typically the Browser Forward button

Your javascript code will be

```
var mouseWheelClick = new MouseEvent( "click", { "button": 1, "which": 1 });
document.getElementById('#elementToClick').dispatchEvent(mouseWheelClick)
```

Then just simply

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.execute_script(javascript_code)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to execute some javascript code.

```
 browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,500)")
 time.sleep(3)
 browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,500)")
 time.sleep(3)
```

This command to scroll the mouse down two times.